# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2

Tags: selenium

I am running data-driven testing reading data from an excel file and I have an excel reader class in a utility package. below is my test case. But I am encountering "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2. Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

```java
public class SignInTest {

    @Test(dataProvider = "TestData")
    public void signInPageTest(String user, String pwd) throws IOException {
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage();
        homePage.clickTestStore();
        StoreHomePage storeHomePage = new StoreHomePage();
        storeHomePage.clickSignInBtn();
        SignInPage signInPage = new SignInPage();
        signInPage.enterEmailID(user);
        signInPage.enterPassword(pwd);
        signInPage.signOutBtn();
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "TestData")
    public Object[][] getData() throws IOException {
        ExcelReader excelReader = new ExcelReader(excelPath);
        int totalRows = excelReader.getRowCount("test1");
        int totalCells = excelReader.getCellCount("test1", 1);
        String testData[][] = new String[totalRows][totalCells];
        for (int rowNum = 1; rowNum <= totalRows; rowNum++) { //1
            for (int colNum = 0; colNum <= totalCells; colNum++) { //0
                testData[rowNum-1][colNum] = excelReader.getCellData("test1", rowNum, colNum);
            }
         }
         return testData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, heaps, I fixed it myself just changed <= to < in the for loop :-)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As there are two `for`-loops, `in the for loop` is ambiguous